# Using core-plot, how can you convert a touched point to the plot space?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I have a very simple graph that I want to enable touch on, I have the
first part working:

plotSpace.delegate = self;

and the method:

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space
shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSLog(@"touched at: x: %f y: %f", point.x, point.y);
}
```

How do I convert the point "point" to the plot space of my graph?

I can see the methods, but Im unsure on how to use them, the doco,
although large, doesnt really describe them well enough :)

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit, I forgot about this question, thanks for the reply Steve.

I did get it solved too, here is my implementation (im extending `CPXYGraph`)

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point {

    CPScatterPlot *plot = (CPScatterPlot*)[[self allPlots] objectAtIndex: 0];
    CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [plot convertPoint:point toLayer:plot];

    if ([plot containsPoint:pointInPlotArea]) {
        CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace*)[self defaultPlotSpace];
        NSDecimal touchDataPoint[2];
        [plotSpace plotPoint:touchDataPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
    }
}
```

touchDataPoint then contains the coords that the user has touched.